# Dynamic changes in ASP:GridView column

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-3.5, gridview

I have created a GridView whose columns are dynamically created based on my data source. One of the column is a status field which displays Yes?No image based on the status field in database.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">                                                                 
   <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Image runat="server" ImageAlign="Middle" ID="imgStatus" ImageUrl= '<%# "/images/actions/" + ((Convert.ToInt32(Eval("StatusFlag")) == 0) ? "actionInActive.gif" : "actionActive.gif") %>' ToolTip='<%# ((Convert.ToInt32(Eval("StatusFlag")) == 0) ? "No" : "Yes") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="40px"/>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

But, displaying status for every row in table is generating a lot of visual noise on page. So, instead of this approach I would like to display only yes status if there are more of entries on page and display both [Yes/No] icons if entries are few in number.

Can anyone provide some suggestions for how can this be achieved?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What could i understand by your question is that you want two thing

*). If there are few record then you want to show two thing in each row one is status image and status.

*). If there are a lot of record then you only want to display status text not image.

If i am right then solution is here:

Add two control in ItemTemplate Image and html label and based on condition change their Visibility.Like this

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Image Visible='<%# Check(Convert.ToString(Eval(Image))) %>' ID="img" runat="server" ImageUrl='<% Eval(Image) %>' /> 
       // for ImageUrl, you can put more condition for 'yes' and 'no' image.
       <asp:Label Visible='<%# Check(Convert.ToString(Eval(Image)))  %>' ID="status" Text='<% Eval(Status) %>' runat = "server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Now in your data source you have to make some change according to your need like..
On Binding you will decide weather you want to show image or not if not then update data source's image value to '#'. Now Check(string imageUrl) is the code behind function

```
   public bool Check(string title)
    {
        if (title == "#")
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

And in future, if you want to show image only on some rows then you will have to make only a little change on your that particular code which is for updating image url and other will automatically will run.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily hide the whole column like this.

```
myGridView.DataBind();
if (myGridView.Rows.Count > Threshold)
    myGridView.Columns[StatusColumnIndex].Visible = false;
```

To display only "Yes" entries you could use LINQ to filter when you bind.

```
if (myData.Length > Threshold)
{
    myGridView.DataSource = myData.Where(d => d.Status == Status.Yes);
    myGridView.Columns[StatusColumnIndex].Visible = false;
}
else
{
    myGridView.DataSource = myData;
    myGridView.Columns[StatusColumnIndex].Visible = true;
}
myGridView.DataBind();
```